# Node.js - is there a way to read an array in storage, by index?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, memory, storage

Disclaimer - I'm still a beginner, so it's definitely possible that I'm thinking about this in entirely the wrong way!

I'm running a Javascript application (in Node.js) which needs to populate a database - specifically, the database is an 88-million-element array where integers are inserted (non-sequentially) using a hash function.

Holding the entire array in memory causes the heap to overflow, and really I only need to access one element at a time. The data structure is a tree, so I will need to continually access individual elements in the array (representing nodes) to extend them and keep populating the data structure.

Is there a way to, say, access element 5,000,000 in this data structure without loading the rest of the array - and without holding the entire thing in memory?

Each lookup needs to be quick, so I think a full-on database software is unlikely to be the best option. I've been using Node's fs module, and splitting the array into lots of small sub-arrays which can be read one at a time, but I feel like I'm missing something here!

Comment: Why don;t you request rows by some chunks using OFFSET/LIMIT features in a DB (if possible)?

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Comment: @Anatoly - thank you! I think the 'offset' feature was what I was looking for :)

Comment: besides doing the query input would also need chunking, lots to think about when handling 88million things

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `LIMIT/OFFSET` feature in a DB to request rows by small chunks.